# How to insert in .php?id= in my php code

Tags: php

Pls am new to programming

Pls sir I have being seeing this in many php files .php?id=3

But I don't understand how it works or how to put it in my code,

Comment: This is a very basic question and you should be able to make a search by yourself to find tons of books/tutorials for php novices. Do you know php.net? For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good/useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

This is called the [query string](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), it's a way of passing parameters to your page.

You can access them in the php using the `$_GET` superglobal like so:

```
var_dump( $_GET['id'] );
```

Tips for using query string variables:

- Check it is set before trying to use it: `isset($_GET['id'])` because you can't be sure it will be there.
- This is "user input" and so you should not trust it implicitly. Whatever you do with user input you should use the appropriate security mechanism to sanitize it to prevent vulnerabilities.
- If you generate a link with dynamic query string variables then be sure to use [URL encoding/Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which can be done with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).